# what is a render target in opengl?

Tags: opengl

Just as the title says, what it a render target in OpenGL? I am so new to OpenGL and all the websites I've seen are quite confusing to me.

Is it just a buffer where I put stuff that will be used later for rendering?

If you could provide a good reference to read about it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A render buffer is any specially created single buffer to which part of rendering may be directed. A colour buffer is the most obvious example, a depth buffer probably the second-most obvious.

A frame buffer is a bound collection of render buffers, e.g. it could be the combination of a colour buffer and a depth buffer. It may also use a texture as the destination for one of those streams of information instead of a render buffer (caveats apply but not relevantly).

Textures are not render buffers and render buffers are not textures. They're distinct things, even though a frame buffer can use either as a target. So a render target is the collective term for either a render buffer or a texture being used as the target for rendering.

The phrase is informally defined but is recognised by Kronos — e.g. the GL 4.4 spec refers to `GL_ARB_draw_buffers` as being "the name string for multiple render targets" but that specification never mentions 'render targets', or even uses the word 'target'. Instead it defines the mechanism that allows multiple colour buffers to be simultaneous named targets. So the two things taken together imply the definution above.